# Trying to read XML attributes via LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

xDoc variable loads the XML content but I am not able to retrieve any information. It comes back NULL:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(Config.CredentialFileName);

//method 1
IEnumerable<XElement> rows = from row in xDoc.Descendants("domain")
                             where (string)row.Attribute("name") == "TEST"
                             select row;
//method 2
var list = xDoc.Descendants("domain")
    .Select(d => new
    {
        name = d.Attribute("name").Value,
        username = d.Attribute("username").Value,
        password = d.Attribute("password").Value //,
    })
    .Where(a => a.name == "TEST")
    .ToList();
```

XML file:

```
<domains>
  <domain name="TEST" userName="test" password="tSEvmlsmwEkjSxUwrCVf3G6"/>
</domains>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method works just fine with xml you provided. Make sure you are parsing xml with exactly same structure. Also check that you have at least one domain element with name equal to `TEST`. And make sure you don't have namespaces defined in your xml.

Second method has typo in `userName` attribute name (you have lower case `username`):

```
var list = xDoc.Descendants("domain")
                .Select(d => new {
                    name = d.Attribute("name").Value,
                    username = d.Attribute("userName").Value, // <-- typo here
                    password = d.Attribute("password").Value
                })
                .Where(a => a.name == "TEST")
                .ToList();
```

---

Also, I'd recommend to use casting instead of reading node `Value` property, because getting this property will throw an exception if node not exist.

```
var domains = from d in xDoc.Descendants("domain")
              let name = (string)d.Attribute("name")
              where name == "TEST"
              select new {
                  Name = name,
                  Username = (string)d.Attribute("userName"),
                  Password = (string)d.Attribute("password")
              };
```

Comment: after I removed .Elements and used .Descendents it worked ! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See below.

```
  var xDoc= XElement.Load(Config.CredentialFileName);             

var result =  xDoc.Elements("domain").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("TEST")).ToList();
```

Comment: @Max it should return 1 item. are you sure the xml file is ok.